# Error when importing data into sample DB2 database

Tags: sql, db2

I'm trying to follow the spatial data tutorial on IBM's website, located here: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/tutorials/dm-1202db2spatialdata1/

I'm trying to work with the hospital data that they provide, and am currently attempting to import hospitals.csv using the provided create_hospitals.sql

However, when I open create_hospitals in Data Studio, it's filled with a bunch of errors that have very poor explanations for why they're an error (and since I haven't even written this code, I assume that it should work as is).

Every single one of the first 15 lines throws an error, usually "Multiple markers at this line." No clue what this means or what I should do to fix it. Here are the first 5 lines which are all erroring (probably because the import is failing to be recognized as a valid command):

```
import from "hospitals.csv" of del 
modified by coldel, decpt. 
method p (1, 2, 3) 
messages "import.msg" 
insert into test.hospitals (name, longitude, latitude);
```

I imported all the contents from the sample SQL scripts and sample data files that IBM provides in the link above, including hospitals.csv, into my Data Studio project. All the files are currently in my project's folder.

How in the world can I get this import statement to not throw an error? What am I missing here?

I'm working with DB2 version 11.1 and IBM Data Studio 4.1.2, and I've used the sample database before for other tasks and queries, so the connection side of things should be fine.

Comment: Notice how the tutorial says nothing about Data Studio. It instructs you to use the DB2 command line processor to run the scripts.

Comment: @fict1080 You need to open a *DB2 Command Window*, which looks like a normal DOS prompt.  Then you can run the commands like `db2 -tvf ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix my issue by typing "quit" in the db2 command line processor, navigating to the directory where the sql file was located, and typing the full command in question: "db2 -tvf create_hospitals.sql"

I needed to make sure that I had enabled spatial support on the database before doing this, though that was as simple as typing "db2se enable_db sample" in the command line before executing create_hospitals. Took a while to execute, but didn't hang.

The db2 processor prompt wasn't able to process the command line parameters that I was trying to feed it, or execute an entire sql script file. So I had to type quit first and use the normal windows cmd.

I guess there are syntax differences between the SQL that IBM's DB2 can execute through the command line and the SQL that IBM's Data Studio can run, because there are still a lot of syntax errors if I try to run create_hospitals in DS. But since I got it working through the cmd, everything is fine and the question is answered.

Thanks!